# Webpage get's corrupted when printing on certain browsers

Tags: html, printing, visual-artifacts

Some users report artifacts when printing webpage. I can't duplicate it on my IE10 browser. I think they use IE8/9

Any pointers on what should be done to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Google fonts on webpage. Modified print.css to use standard (Arial) fonts and all fixed. Looks like not all printer drivers like fancy fonts.